# NSTableView illegal data source

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm reading the book "Beginning Mac Programming" by Tim Isted and I'm stuck with a program dealing with NSTableView.
I have a Cocoa app inherited from NSDocument. The app contains an NSTableView. I've set the data source of the Table View to File's owner. Upon execution I get  *** Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Interface of MyDocument.h is

```
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *newItemTextField;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *shoppingListTableView; 
    NSMutableArray *shoppingListArray;
}
-(IBAction)addNewItemToShoppingList:(id)sender;
-(void)dealloc;
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView;
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
@end
```

while implementation is

```
#import "MyDocument.h"

@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        shoppingListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pane",@"latte",@"pasta", nil];

    }

    return self;
}

-(IBAction)addNewItemToShoppingList:(id)sender{
    NSString *item = [newItemTextField stringValue];
    [shoppingListArray addObject:item];
    [shoppingListTableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"allocated");

}
-(void)dealloc{
    [shoppingListArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView{
    return [shoppingListArray count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    return [shoppingListArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}
```

What am I doing wrong ??? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You've implemented `numberOfRowsInTableView`, but you needed to implement `numberOfRowsInTableView:`. The correct signature is:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
```